# Minimize overhead with running session in tensorflow

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, session

I want to do Monte-Carlo (MC) sampling from a distribution defined as a DNN in TensorFlow. The sampling code requires a custom function which is difficult to use inside TensorFlow code.

Since MC requires a huge number of calls of the DNN, I have to run (and close) the session a huge number of times to sample from the DNN. Profiling showed that the overhead associated with `session.run()` is the current bottleneck in my code.

TensorFlow appears to have a [C++ API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/cc), but it also requires running a session.

1. Does anyone know if the overhead of `session.run()` is reduced in the C++ version of TensorFlow? This would be nice to know before I spend time re-writing my code.
2. What is an efficient TensorFlow way of doing MC sampling which makes use of an external (python or c++) function [i.e. cannot be defined within TensorFlow]?

Comment: I have the same problem right now. Did you find any solution for yourself?

Comment: It seems like there is no way to call Tflow without a session. I found two ways out:
(i) export the weights from Tflow before you do the sampling; This has the disadvantage that you'd need to reconstruct the DNN outside Tflow to be able to evaluate the data.
(ii) define your own Tflow operator in which you define the sampling function. There are instructions how to do this on the Tflow website. That said, I ended up using (i).